# How can I see the $_POST variable in PhpStorm when debugging a remote server with Xdebug?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm relatively new to PHP so please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

I have set up an Apache server on a Raspberry Pi and successfully configured Xdebug with PhpStorm and can set breakpoints etc.

I am trying initially a basic html form with an Ajax POST request to run a PHP file to do validation. It successfully sends the request as PhpStorm breaks at a breakpoint set in the PHP file, however there is no `$_POST` variable in the debugger, only `$_COOKIE` and `$_SERVER`.

If anyone has any thoughts that would be much appreciated.

JavaScript in html file:

```js
 $("#frmContact").on('submit',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mail-status").hide();
        $('#send-message').hide();
        $('#loader-icon').show();
        $.ajax({
          url: "contact.php",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            "name": $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            "email": $('input[name="email"]').val(),
            "selection": $('input[name="selection"]').val(),
            "content": $('textarea[name="formText"]').val()
          },
          success: function (response) {
            $("#mail-status").show();
            $('#loader-icon').hide();
            if (response.type == "error") {
              $('#send-message').show();
              $("#mail-status").attr("class", "error");
            } else if (response.type == "message") {
              $('#send-message').hide();
              $("#mail-status").attr("class", "success");
            }
            $("#mail-status").html(response.text);
          },
          error: function () {
          }
        });
  });
```

php.ini file (on Raspberry Pi)

```
;XDebug
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.2.201
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.show_local_vars=on
xdebug.dump.SERVER=REQUEST_URI,DOCUMENT_ROOT,SCRIPT_FILENAME
xdebug.default_enable=1
```

Image of the debugger in PhpStorm:
[image: PhpStorm debugger]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630862/xdebug-post-requests-with-phpstorm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279815/how-to-debug-ajax-post-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug

Comment: @user128422 I suggest you this: create another PHP file with just `<?php phpinfo();` content inside. Call it `test.php` or something like that. Now change your JS code and send your data to that test.php instead of `contact.php`. Then just look at `_SERVER` variables there -- what request is actually that etc. Do that with Network panel of your Developer Tools in browser active -- look at what is the actual request is -- did it actually sent the ritgh data? Maybe there was some redirect in place etc?

Comment: The reason I'm asking this: maybe your request is not going through properly or it does not send the data with it (that's why `$_POST` is not there -- PhpStorm may be hiding empty global variables, check options in that Debug toolwindow). Your web browser should tell what exactly is getting sent and if it has any redirects etc.

Comment: I think you may be on to it, there are in fact empty global variables, and the request in the developer tools doesn't seem to have any of the form data so I assume theres a problem with the body of the ajax request? The test.php is returning the phpinfo page so I assume the request itself is working.

Comment: Yep, the problem is the request, tried it with some hard coded data and it's all working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check how your request appears in the Network tab of Developer Tools in your browser.

The reason I'm asking this: it's possible that your request is not going through properly or it does not send the data with it (that will explain why you cannot see `$_POST` variable there: PhpStorm can hide such empty global variables (check the options for that in IDE's Debug toolwindow)).

Your web browser should tell what exactly is getting sent and if it has any redirects etc (e.g. POST data is usually lost on 302 redirect and request verb should change to GET here). If request contains no POST data then it must be an issue in the JS code that collects it.